# My world won't let me use commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So in my Minecraft world, a ton of weird things have been going on, and it's only me who is in this world. My world would not load some chunks but I fixed that, now I try to set the time to day or night, but the commands doesn't work, or show up in the chat window, so I know its not even executing the command.

Does anyone know a solution???

Comment: Welcome to Arqade!! just for some clarity is it just the time change command that is not working or is it all of the commands?

Comment: Do any red messages appear?